# How to remove parenthesis from NSArray ((909093498))?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, nsstring

```
    // Form the query.
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select firstTimeStamp from activityTimeStamp where userId=\"%@\" And buddyId=\"%@\"",[PFUser currentUser].username,buddyId];    
        // Get the results.
        if (self.arrTimeStampInfo != nil) {
            self.arrTimeStampInfo = nil;
        }
        // Getting Data into Array
        self.arrTimeStampInfo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];

       // Get the results.
    if (self.arrTimeStampInfo != nil) {
        self.arrTimeStampInfo = nil;
    }

    NSLog(@"Array containing records%@", self.arrTimeStampInfo);
and it prints (    (1111132324)   ) 
    NSString *string = [_arrTimeStampInfo objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSLog(@"this is string timestamp %@",string);
```

I am not able to succeed in converting `NSarray` element into `NSInteger` or `long` in order to do some arithmetic operations on it. I have tried lot of codes but getting an error which is:

```
[__NSArrayM stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: can you show _arrTimeStampInfo content.. it seems that objectAtIndex: 0 its a kind of Array not string

Comment: (
        (
        1481824800
    )
) this is the content inside the array.

Comment: Please print the _arrTimeStampInfo content to see the structure

Comment: use this to debug your code:                                                                              if ([[_arrTimeStampInfo objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        //the content is array
        
    }else if ([[_arrTimeStampInfo objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        // the content is string
    }

Comment: its an array, but i want to save this value as integer, but i think because of () i am not able to save it.

Comment: Your `self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:` method is returning an array of arrays. Since you didn't show that code, no one can help.

Comment: @rmaddy that's what I expected